# Can you input into the text field of a prompt box using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I'm trying to input characters into a prompt box like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt). However, I can't seem to find any way of doing this. There are some useful methods that I found in the [Puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#dialogdefaultvalue) for dialog boxes but none that could really help me with what I'm trying to do. I was wondering if there are any creative workarounds to accomplish this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [dialog](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#event-dialog) event. Once there, you can use [dialog.accept](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#dialogacceptprompttext) to set the text. This will input "Stack Overflow" in your example:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt");
const frame = (await page.frames())[1];

page.on('dialog', dialog => {
    dialog.accept("Stack Overflow!");
});

await frame.click("BUTTON")

browser.close();
```

Comment: what if it has 2 input fields? how do you target each? ex. username and password

Comment: If that's basic authentication you can use page.authenticate https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/ffec2475d0cae61ddb4d6d32956408afe836552e/test/network.spec.ts#L537

Comment: I tried it "  await page.authenticate({
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
  });
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');" and got this error "Runtime error encountered: Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 401)"

Comment: You should create a new question explaining your scenario. Authentication is not a dialog  like the ones  `dialog` tries to solve.